# Uniform convergence of sequence of functions.

Tags: real-analysis

We have a sequence {$f_n$} with $f_n(x) = \Theta_{([n, n+1])}(x)$ on $E=[0, \infty)$.
$\Theta_U = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if } x\in U\\ 0 &\text{if } x\not\in U \end{cases}.\\$

I looked at pointwise convergence, but am having trouble about whether or not it is uniform. It seems that $\forall x$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ you would get $0$ since $n$ would be greater than the interval that $x$ is in. But when trying to look at $\sup_{x\in E}\mid f_n(x) - f(x)\mid$ I get confused.

I have a similar problem $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \Theta_{([n, n+1])}(x)$ on $E=[0, \infty)$ which is more straightforward which I believe would be uniformly convergent since $f(x)=0$, making the rest more simple. But I am still new to the topic and don't quite have a firm understanding, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the negation of the definition of uniform convergence.

> $\exists \varepsilon  > 0{\text{ }}s.t.{\text{ }}\forall N > 0,\left| {{f_n}\left( x \right) - f\left( x \right)} \right| \geqslant \varepsilon $ for some $n > N$ and $x \in E$.

Put $\varepsilon  = \frac{1}{2}$, $\forall N > 0$, fix ${n_0} > N$ and let $x \in \left[ {n_{0},n_{0} + 1} \right]$, then we get the result that $f_{n}$ does not converge uniformly to  $0$.

Comment: Thank you, very useful. Never thought about looking at it this way.